# Vpn protocol / Adding a web domain / How to do it manually using OpenVpn

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, domain

Can someone explain to me what ufo vpn is doing when i use the protocol mode C, i used to access the internet using this vpn, but now they dont support this option on Android, and i cant connect on PC. I want to learn how to manually do the same. [Protocol C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qv1xy.png)

Answer (score -1):

I think the only way to get a concrete answer would be to ask UFO VPN - these are not "standard protocols" - it is a term they have concocted.

At a guess, they are using different mechanisms to connect OpenVPN, and possibly also influence the way routing is handled.  I somewhat suspect that Protocol A is standard UDP, Protocol C opens a tunnel on TCP port 443 to punch through school proxies, but what protocol B and D are are anyone's guess.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?